# What happened to Hector Mendoza in House of Cards?

Tags: character, house-of-cards

In Season 3 Episode 8 of House of Cards, during Frank's "breaking the fourth wall" instance, he said:

> that Hector Mendoza was replaced as the Senate majority leader because *he declared a couple of paid speeches* as income?

What does that mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quite the opposite - he didn't declare them, which basically means that he lied in his taxes.

From [HoD wiki](http://house-of-cards.wikia.com/wiki/Hector_Mendoza):

> It revealed later in the season that amidst a scandal of accepting
>   undeclared payments for speeches, Mendoza had resigned.

According to what Frank said in this episode this came out because a document "leaked".

Comment: Not entirely related, but is it known if this was a plot decision or was the actor removed from the show for some reason? It seemed very abrupt.

Comment: @pedro.m. According to the info you can find for example [here](http://www.reddit.com/r/HouseOfCards/comments/2xp44x/so_mendoza/) this is due to his involvement in show [American Crime](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3488298/), but since it's not related to the plot I didn't mention it in my answer.

Comment: Ah I had wondered about that. That event just seemed to have come out of no where and I was wondering if the actor had to leave the show. Thanks for the info!